# Drupal 7, Omega subtheme where to put template_feed_icons function?

Tags: theming

I would like to alter the feed icon that appears in the built-in syndicate block. Following the basic Drupal instructions, you are supposed to copy the theme_feed_icons function to template.php and rename "theme" to whatever your theme's name is.

If I do that, I get a white screen if I use the format of "my_theme_name_alpha_feed_icons" for the function name. Any other name format doesn't have any effect. It does not matter whether I put this function in preprocess/preprocess-page.inc or in template.php.

Can someone explain how I can alter the theme_feed_icons function using Drupal 7 and an omega subtheme?

Comment: Have you tried `function MYTHEME_feed_icons($vars) { ...` (where `MYTHEME` is the name of your theme) in template.php?

Comment: The Omega theme system suggests not to put things in template.php. But if that is truly where to put it in the Omega theme, then what should the function name be since mytheme_alpha_feed_icons is the only name that causes an effect, but it only causes a white screen.

Comment: @Diane Not using template.php in Omega subthemes is not strictly true.  The Alpha portion of the Omega theme provides a method for splitting out preprocess and process functions into include files.  Therefore those are discouraged in template.php.  Theme overrides, form alters, etc, have to go somewhere, and template.php is it.

Comment: @MPD Any reason why the function fails? It gives me a WSOD if I write it my_theme_alpha_feed_icons($vars){ } It doesn't do anything at all if I write it my_theme_feed_icons($vars){ print "foo"; }

Comment: Looks like the WSOD was caused by some former files not being written to the server. But I still cannot get my function to change the feed icon.

Comment: Alright, I finally got it working.